# php explode() delimiter issue

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP so this may be a simple fix.
I have a text file named `textt.txt` that looks like this:

> South East asia,2222,code1
>   winter break,3333,code2

My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php       
$x = file_get_contents('textt.txt');
        $y = explode("\r\n", $x);
        $z = $y[0];
    echo $z;
?>
```

The outcome of this is:

> South East asia,2222,code1

I would like it to return only:

> South East Asia.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode()` again on the comma. Your first call to `explode()` splits the string by lines, each containing a comma-separated string.

```
<?php       
$x = file_get_contents('textt.txt');
        $y = explode("\r\n", $x);

        // $y[0] now contains the first line "South East asia,2222,code1"
        // explode() that on ","
        $parts = explode(",", $y[0]);

        // And retrieve the first array element
        $z = $parts[0];
    echo $z;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to split it on \r\n like you do, and then loop trough the array and explode it on comma to only get the region:

```
<?php       
$file = file_get_contents('textt.txt');
$fileArray = explode("\r\n", $file);

foreach($fileArray as $value) {
    $region = explode(",", $value);
    echo $region[0] . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty:

```
<?php       
$all_file = file_get_contents('textt.txt');
$lines = explode("\r\n", $all_file);
$first_line = $lines[0];
$items = explode(",", $first_line);
echo $item[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

**South East asia**`,`2222,code1

winter break`,`3333`,`code2

```
$x = file_get_contents('textt.txt');
list($z) = explode(",", $x);
echo $z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you may not want to read the entire file in one shot:

```
$fp = fopen('textt.txt', 'r');
list($z) = fgetcsv($fp);
```